# How to Set Target Platform in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

My problem is: my target platforms in all my workspaces can not be set by Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.2), even though they could (and can) be set by Eclipse Neon. It seems to be possible exactly once per workspace, after that I can neither reset the same target platform, nor switch to an other one.

I'd guess is there is a flag or a setting in the preferences you need to set in Eclipse Oxygen that was not present in Neon, because setting a target platform (and switching between two of them) was very possible. Looks like a caching problem, too.

The error message I'm getting is:

```
An internal error occurred during: 
Install download0
Install download1
Install download2
Install download3
```

And in the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.getArtifact(MirrorRequest.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

And an example for a target platform that does not work is (even though I'm reasonable sure it can't be the target platform, because it works in Neon):

```xml
<location includeAllPlatforms="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit"> 
        <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group"                        version="4.7.2.v20171130-0510" />
</location>
```

I found two bugs with a similar exception: [Bug 506255](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506255) talks about mirrored update sites which I might use? [Bug 379986](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379986) is probably not really relevant, because it's about the *Check for Updates* function.

I deleted the bundle pool folders (found via *Preferences -> Oomph -> Bundle Pools*) but the problem persisted, this time even the first time I opened a target platform in a brand new workspace.

I **can** resolve the very same target platform in Tycho (but -again- I can do that too using Eclipse Neon).

I found a way to resolve a target platform that produces that error. Let's say I have a target platform with 25 locations. I remove one location after the other and try to resolve the target platform. At about 19 it actually does (that number might be random, but it's not bound to a specific location). Then I add the locations again one by one. It does not work if I add them all at once for some reasons. When I get to the original target platform it now resolves.

How do I set target platforms in Oxygen?

**Followup:** Now one of hour hundreds of project has the same (or a very similar) exception when being build on the Jenkins:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:666)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:723)
at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getArtifactFromOneMirror(RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:229)
at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getArtifactFromAnyMirror(RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:212)
at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.access$1(RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:207)
at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider$1.perform(RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:187)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:707)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifacts(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:778)
at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getArtifactFromAnyChildRepository(RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:199)
at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getArtifactFromAnyFormatAvailableInRepository(RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:168)
at org.eclipse.tycho.repository.p2base.artifact.repository.RepositoryArtifactProvider.getArtifactFromAnySource(RepositoryArtifactProvider.java:154)
```

Comment: There should no space after `/updates/4.7`. Can you give a step-by-step instruction how to reproduce this issue? There are many ways to define and use a target platform.

Comment: @howlger What _I_ do to reproduce the bug is to check out any of our target platforms that worked with Neon and continue working for e.g. Tycho and then double click the target platform. There seems to be no single `<location>` responsible for the error message, but I'm trying to find a minimal target platform right now. It _seems_ to work once we go from 20 locations to 19, but that's just another theory.

Comment: @SteffiS. I'm struggling as well with the same issue, and the logs and there's very little information around the web for it. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @DiegoLópez No :( I guess the solution is to NOT use Oxygen yet.

Comment: @SteffiS. Thanks for the answer. Well, for me, I also get the same errors `An internal error occurred during: "Install download0".` with Neon and Kepler, not only Oxygen.

Comment: @DiegoLópez Interesting. Maybe that info can help to figure out what the problem is. Are you using any kind of public repositories? Like the ones of the Eclipse platform?

Comment: @SteffiS. Hey, I managed to get a better description of the issue by doing the following: Remove the eclipse repository (Mark the repo and click remove) and then adding it again (click Add... and selecting the necessary plugins). Then I got a better description of the exception.

Comment: @DiegoLópez What is the better description? Maybe it helps to resolve the problem?

Comment: @SteffiS. I solved my problems by downloading the repositories to the hard drive and add them as folders. The description message was very specific for my project, about not finding a library that I needed.